# Calculate the crescent moon width using Skyfield

Tags: python, skyfield

How can I calculate the topocentric crescent moon width for a given time and location? I've searched through the Skyfield documentation and can't find anything.

If there is no direct api what is the formulae required to do it indirectly?

The closest I came to was this https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/examples.html#what-phase-is-the-moon-tonight.

But this is not topocentric.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have:

```
from skyfield.api import wgs84, load
from math import degrees, cos, asin, floor

ts = load.timescale()
eph = load('de421.bsp')

sun, earth, moon = eph['sun'], eph['earth'], eph['moon']

time = ts.tt(2023, 6, 1, 21, 30)  # June 1st 2023 9:30pm

# the location of the observer i.e. Hyde Park, London
observer = earth + wgs84.latlon(
    51.51, -0.165, 30)  #latitude, longitude, elevation 

# calculate the topocentric position of the sun and the moon
sun_topocentric = observer.at(time).observe(sun).apparent()
moon_topocentric = observer.at(time).observe(moon).apparent()

# calculate elongation from topocentric position of the sun relative to the moon
elongation = sun_topocentric.separation_from(moon_topocentric)

# calculate the geocentric position of the moon from the earth
difference = moon.at(time) - earth.at(time)
# retrieve the distance is km
moon_to_earth_km = difference.distance().km


moon_radius_km = 1737.1
moon_radius_degrees = degrees(asin(moon_radius_km / moon_to_earth_km))

crescent_width_degrees = moon_radius_degrees * (1 - (cos(elongation.radians)))

print(crescent_width_degrees)
```